# Undefined method `donation_interests?' for nil:NilClass, multiply checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I try to design the check box for the `donation_interest` but I don't know why I get this error? I will appreciate if you can help me.

```
module DonorProfilesHelper
  def checked(area)
     @donor_profiles.donation_interests.nil? ? false: @donor_profiles.donation_interests.match(area)
   end  
end
```

**class DonorProfilesController < ApplicationController**

```
  def donor_profile_params
    params.require(:donor_profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :description,
                                            :date_created, :address, :phone_number,
                                            :email,:sort_type, 
                                            donations_attributes: [:amount, :created_at],donation_interests:[])
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :donor_profiles

  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'

  get 'sessions/new'

  root                  'static_pages#home'
  get     'donors'  =>  'donor_profiles#index'
```

**donor_profile.rb**

```
class DonorProfile < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :donations_attributes
    has_many :donations
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :donations
    scope :donation_interests, -> donation_interests { where donation_interests: donation_interests }    
    def fullname
      "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
    end
      before_save do
        self.donation_interests.gsub!(/[\[\]\"]/,"") if attribute_present?("donation_interests")
      end
end
```

Comment: You would usually set `donor_profiles` in controller action, but since you haven't posted full controller code, I don't know why it returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Since View Helpers in rails are mixed-in to be available for all views I don't think it's good idea to use `@donor_profiles` instance variable inside your helper since this means that you should call this helper in a view that is rendered after an action which sets it up, and you can't use it in any other views.

This can work for common instance variables that can be set in `ApplicationController` like `@current_user` for example.

So I would re-write the helper like this

```
module DonorProfilesHelper
  def checked(donor_profiles, area)
     donor_profiles.donation_interests.nil? ? false:  donor_profiles.donation_interests.match(area)
   end  
end
```

and when using it in your view pass the `donor_profile` object, it'll be easier to find out if it's `nil` then.

You also can use `try` method to be nil-safe `donor_profiles.try(:donation_interests)` which will return `nil` if `donor_profiles` is `nil` and not throw an error

Comment: Thanks for replying. I re-write the helper as you said but I got the new error                         here is error:                      wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Comment: when you re-write the helper like this you need to pass 2 arguments to it the `donor_profile` and the `area` not just the `area` as before

Comment: like this   def checked(donor_profiles, area)? I think I did same thing as you said. Sorry. I am new to the ruby